# Display message after success of function with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've trying to display message for success when ajax request finish but no luck so far.
This is the html part

```
<a href="#" class="bookmarked has-tooltip" data-title="Add to favorite" id="'.$row['image_id'].'"></a>
<span id="message"></span>
```

and this is the ajax part

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.bookmarked', $('.buttons')).click(function(){
$.post('misc/add_favorites.php', { 
    image_id: $(this).attr('id') }, 
       success: function(){
        $('#message').html('<div id="alertFadeOut" style="color: green">Added to favorites!</div>'); // Diplay message with a fadeout
          $('#alertFadeOut').fadeOut(3000, function () {
              $('#alertFadeOut').text('');
          }); 
        });
    console.log(data);
});

});
```

Also in console I got this erroe

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Where exactly does the console point that error to?

Comment: On success function - `success: function(){`

Comment: whats this ? `$('.bookmarked', $('.buttons'))` ?

Comment: @Rahul http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont use `success` within post, its not same as ajax

```
<script>    


$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.bookmarked', .buttons').click(function(){
                $.post('misc/add_favorites.php', 
                { 
                    "image_id": $(this).attr('id'),
                },
                 function(){
                $('#message').html('<div id="alertFadeOut" style="color: green">Added to favorites!</div>'); // Diplay message with a fadeout
                  $('#alertFadeOut').fadeOut(3000, function () {
                      $('#alertFadeOut').text('');
                  }); 
              });

            console.log(data);
        });


});


 </script>
```

see this may work

### New edit

In you php file

```
 if($result > 0 ){
 echo 1;
 } else {
 echo 0;
 }
```

Now your function inside your ajax call

```
function(data){
  if(data == 1){
        $('#message').html('<div id="alertFadeOut" style="color: green">Added to favorites!</div>'); // Diplay message with a fadeout
                      $('#alertFadeOut').fadeOut(3000, function () {
                          $('#alertFadeOut').text('');
                      }); 
    }
 }
```

Comment: This work for the ajax part.. not getting any error and is saving into DB but there is no `#message`

Comment: check if your message div is hidden or getting any html or not

Comment: Yes, yes I saw it.. it's there. Thank's for the help!

Comment: happy to help. @JasonPaddle mark my answer verified too, it may help others

Comment: I will in 3 minutes ;)

Comment: yeah sure when ever you want

Comment: Can I ask what are the option instead of `<a hreff...>` because if I'm on the middle of the page and click Add to Favorite icon this href back mi on the beginning of the page which is not good.?

Comment: Also in that way even if is not `success` i.e. this `image_id` already is added to favorite I still get the message for successful add

Comment: instead of  `href="#"` use `href="javascript:;"`

Comment: you should return something from server side and use it as response

Comment: I have this on server side `if( $result > 0) { echo 'already added';}`. So how to show this. Do I need some error function or something?